# Ground state wavefunction of Double-well potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

How does the ground state wavefunction ($\psi_0$) will look like for a double-well potential if the barrier height is lower than the ground state energy?

It looks like, if the barrier height is lower than the ground-state energy there is no change in the wavefunction. It only matters when the barrier height is comparable to or more than the ground state energy then there is a dip in the wavefunction.

**Now my concern is: if the potential is deeper particle faces more force. Therefore, I would expect there will be some changes in the $\psi_0$ or $|\psi_0|^2$as particle spend less time in the deeper side than the barrier.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Have you made any attempt to solve this problem on your own? Show effort! Help us help you.

Comment: @Daniel..I did some attempt. Please see the updated one.

Comment: If the barrier height is lower than some fixed energy (which you call the ground state energy), and atom seeks the part of the position with the lowest potential, then the atom is attracted to the center of your "barrier", no? And that will be the ground state energy of the system. It's as if you are trying to lower the barrier in a double well so much, that the double well transforms into a triple well.